# How do I setup multiple minicom / Cisco console server sessions without too much hassle?

Tags: ssh, cisco, serial-port, telnet

I'm working on my CCNA and have 4 switches & 4 routers which make up my main lab.
I bought two quad port USB to Serial (1 USB to 4 Serial) Adapters onto the ends of which I've attached 8 Serial rollover cables.

Those USBs are plugged into a P4 Ubuntu server and I can successfully ssh into that server and manage any of the devices using minicom, as myself as I'm in the dialout group.

I have a minicom save file for USB[0-7] and have used ln to link SW1-4, R1-4 so I can "minicom R1", etc.

With my dual monitors, I can have all 8 terminal sessions open - 4 on each screen.

Here's the main thing though: I have to open a terminal on my workstation, SSH across to the access server, then run minicom. I have to do this once for each device. Although that's not a back breaker, I'm sure there must be a simpler way to do it - can I tell my server to expose each serial connection as a telnet or ssh port? I would really like to be able to run a script of some sort that launched all eight sessions in one click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago I was able to make this kind of serial to network redirection using [remserial](http://lpccomp.bc.ca/remserial/):

> **Give access to a RS232 device over a network.**
>
> The computer with the serial port connected to the device (such as a
>   data aquisition device) runs the remserial program:
>
> ```
> remserial -d -p 23000 -s "9600 raw" /dev/ttyS0 &
> ```
>
> This starts the program in daemon mode so that it runs in the
>   background, it waits for connections on port 23000 and sets up the
>   serial port /dev/ttyS0 at 9600 baud. Network connections to port 23000
>   from any machine can then read and write to the device attached to the
>   serial port.
>
> This can be started from /etc/rc.local or as an entry in /etc/inittab
>   or set up as a system service with a file in /etc/rc.init/.

This is what you need:

> **Server farm console control.**
>
> Assuming multiple Linux servers (such as web servers) are set up to
>   have a serial port as their console instead of a monitor/keyboard,
>   their serial ports could be connected to a control server using a
>   multi-port serial board. On the control server, a copy of remserial is
>   run for each server:
>
> ```
> remserial -d -p 23000 -s "115200 raw" /dev/ttyS0
> remserial -d -p 23001 -s "115200 raw" /dev/ttyS1
> remserial -d -p 23002 -s "115200 raw" /dev/ttyS2
> remserial -d -p 23003 -s "115200 raw" /dev/ttyS3
> ```
>
> From any computer on the local network, use a telnet program to
>   connect to the control server on the appropriate port:
>
> ```
> telnet control-server-name 23002
> ```
>
> This would connect through the associated serial port to the desired
>   server's console. This example would then give the user console access
>   to the 3rd server.
>
> Careful scripting such as using the Linux "expect" program could allow
>   batches of commands to be run on each server.

At the end of the page you'll find links to download a precompiled binary for i386 (32-bit) and the source code (if you're running a 64-bit OS or prefer to compile it yourself).

**EDIT**: To add a little automation you can install `expect` and write the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn telnet 192.168.0.1
expect "Username:"
send "your-username\r"
expect "Password:"
send "your-password\r"
expect "#"            <----- prompt character ($ or #)
interact
```

This will automatically telnet to the host login and drop you to the prompt.

Comment: Fantastic! This looks like it will do the job perfectly. I can install password less telnet access, but resrict to internal hosts and I can handle double clicking 8 icons to launch the terminals. Thanks very very much - you've made me very happy!

Comment: @AJRossington Answer updated.

Comment: How do you install `remserial` on ubuntu?  `sudo apt-get install remserial` didn't seem to work.

Comment: @William Install `build-essential` package. Download remserial's [source](http://lpccomp.bc.ca/remserial/remserial-1.4.tar.gz), extract it to a directory, then, in a terminal, `cd` to that directory and run `make`. It's done. The executable will be created in the current directory. You may want to copy it to `/usr/local/bin` for your convenience.